# PDF Generation Using PDFBOX dependecy in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsp, thymeleaf, pdfbox

I'm generating the PDF at the backend side using the pdf-box library. I want to add an image to the pdf. I tried embedding the image into the thymleaf html template but it's not working.
To add an image in pdf there are programmatic ways to do it through java, but my pdf size of pages (no of pages) can increase or decrease, I need to keep my image align to one div so how can I do that?